# Sequelize : Scope with where condition not working with singular and plural

Tags: include, sequelize.js, singular, plural

I am looking to put a valid condition in the child running for a 1: 1 and N: N relationship like this example 1:1

```
// Find all projects with a least one task where task.state === project.state
Project.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Task,
        where: { state: Sequelize.col('project.state') }
    }]
})
```

Only the name of the table changes name from "project" to "projects" depending on the relationship
In this case, 'project.state' will work but a request from a model with an N: N association will give an error :

```
"invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table \" project \ ""
```

the condition should be 'projects.state'

If working if i use "as :project" in include for each query but if anyone has a good idea.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to force sequelize.js to use the original names mentioned in model while creating tables in database you can make sequelize.js to use given names not plural of names

```
var db_instance = new Sequelize(config.DB.database, config.DB.username, config.DB.password, {
  host: config.DB.host,
  dialect: config.DB.dialect,
  define: {
    timestamps: true,
    freezeTableName: true
  },
  logging: false
});
```

OR

You can simply tell Sequelize the name of the table directly as well:

```
sequelize.define('project', {
  // ... (attributes)
}, {
  tableName: 'project'
});
```

You can see both Method in [Documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#table-name-inference) of sequelize.js